# Bootstrap 4 flex system support the specific self-row items in parent column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have following navbar:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
   ......
</div>
```

For example:

```css
.bd-highlight {
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between bd-highlight">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-0">Flex item 1 (LOGO)</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-2 order-lg-1">Flex item 2 (Nav. Menu)</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-1 order-lg-2">Flex item 3 (Search Form)</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-3">Flex item 4 (Acc. Menu)</div>
</div>
```

But my design includes special cases as follows.

**1- Media device ( ≥ 992px ):** all by side.

[image]

**2- Media device ( < 992px ):** all underneath. But `Flex item 2` and `Flex item 3` they're moving. For this I'm using the `order-*` class. *-See above snippet and following image.-* After that, i want self-row side by side ( `1 and 3` ) ( `2 and 4` )

[image]

Everything's okay. I can't find, just how I can get side by side `Flex item 1 - Flex item 3` and `Flex item 2 - Flex item 4`.

*(via self, because parent has column and i can't add more parents because they're moving.)*

**LIKE THIS:**

[image]

Does Bootstrap 4 or flexbox support this action? Is such a thought possible or should I look for solutions in other ways?

For example:

```
<div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-self-row1"></div>
    <div class="flex-self-row1"></div>
    <div class="flex-self-row2"></div>
    <div class="flex-self-row2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your parent as `flex-column`, there is no way to achieve what you want for media device < 992px unless you group Flex item 1 and 3 as a row and Flex item 2 and 4 as another row, or you're willing to duplicate those items and show/hide based on the media queries.

Another approach is to display parent as `flex-row`, and have it `wrap`, and then to set those flex items' width to 50%!

To keep your HTML neat, I was going to use the width utility from Bootstrap to set the widths but too bad the width utility classes don't have responsive variations. Hence I change the HTML layout, add 2 custom classes `.parent` and `.item` and style them using custom styles.

#### HTML

```
<div class="d-flex bd-highlight parent">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-0 item">
        Flex item 1 (LOGO)
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-2 order-lg-1 item">
        Flex item 2 (Nav. Menu)
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-1 order-lg-2 item">
        Flex item 3 (Search Form)
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight order-3 item">
        Flex item 4 (Acc. Menu)
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Media device < 992px

```
.parent {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.parent .item {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[image]

#### Media device >= 992px

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .parent {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .parent .item {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/273412/

Comment: It's wonderful idea. Please correct if I misunderstood, You just solved this with the flex-row both, right? You've never used "column"?

Comment: @l6ls: yes! `flex-flow: row wrap;` set the parent to display as flexbox row and wrappable.